# how to execute multiline shell command in perl?

Tags: perl, shell

I want to run shell command as follow in perl:

```
tar --exclude="*/node_modules" \
--exclude="*/vendor" \
--exclude='.git' \
-zvcf /tmp/robot.tgz .
```

But it seems perl can not excute this:

```
`tar --exclude="cv/node_modules" \
--exclude="*/vendor" \
--exclude='.git' \
-zvcf /tmp/robot.tgz .`;
```

Here is the error:

```
tar: Must specify one of -c, -r, -t, -u, -x
sh: line 1: --exclude=*/vendor: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: --exclude=.git: command not found
sh: line 3: -zvcf: command not found
```

it seems perl treat each line as one command.

Comment: Why not run it as a one-line command instead of a multi-line command.  Perl handles long strings fine.  In any case, you need to double up the backslashes since Perl strips them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, you are right, I handle this in one line ok, but I still try  to do this because one line are to long, sometimes, it is not readable.

Comment: You can always build the one long line by concatenating multiple shorter strings, which doesn't have the readability problems.  But it is also valid to make the request.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update

I apologise. My original diagnosis was wrong

It is hard to clearly express in a post like this the contents of strings that contain Perl escape characters. If anything below is unclear to you then please write a comment to say so. I hope I haven't made things unnecessarily complicated

My original solution below is still valid, and will give you better control over the contents of the command, but my reasons for why the OP's code doesn't work for them were wrong, and the truth offers other resolutions

The problem is that the contents of backticks (or `qx/.../`) are evaluated as a *double-quoted string*, which means that Perl variables and escape sequences like `\t` and `\x20` are expanded before the string is executed. One of the consequences of this is that a backslash is deleted if it is followed by a literal newline, leaving just the newline

That means that a statement like this

```
my $output = `ls \
-l`;
```

will be preprocessed to `"ls \n-l"` and will no longer contain the backslash that is needed to signal to the shell that the newline should be removed (or indeed to get the command passed to the shell in the first place)

Apart from manipulating the command string directly as I described in my original post below, there are two solutions to this. The first is to escape the backslash itself by doubling it up, like this

```
my $output = `ls \\
-l`;
```

which will prevent it from being removed by Perl. That will pass the backslash-newline sequence to the shell, which will remove it as normal

The other is to use `qx'...'` instead of backticks together with single-quote delimiters, which will prevent the contents from being processed as a double-quoted string

```
my $output = qx'ls \
-l';
```

This will work fine unless you have used Perl variables in the string that you want to be interpolated

---

#### Original post

The problem is that the shell removes newlines preceded by backslashes from the command string before executing it. Without that step the command is invalid

So you must do the same thing yourself in Perl, and to do that you must put the command in a temporary variable

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $cmd = <<'END';
tar --exclude="*/node_modules" \
--exclude="*/vendor" \
--exclude='.git' \
-zvcf /tmp/robot.tgz .
END

$cmd =~ s/\\\n//g;

my $output = `$cmd`;
```

There is no need for the backslashes of course; you can simply use newlines and remove those before executing the command

Or you may prefer to wrap the operations in a subroutine, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $output = do_command(<<'END');
tar --exclude="*/node_modules" \
--exclude="*/vendor" \
--exclude='.git' \
-zvcf /tmp/robot.tgz .
END

sub do_command {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    $cmd =~ s/\\\n//g;
    `$cmd`;
}
```

Comment: So Perl, when running `qx//`, behaves somewhat shell-like (according to the "perlop" perldoc), but not quite?

Comment: @sferencik: It's not that straightforward, but `qx//` behaves the same way as [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) which, like much of Perl, is designed to *do what you mean*. Essentially, Perl will start a shell process to execute the command if it finds any *shell metacharacters* in the string, like wildcard file expansion, input and output redirection, pipes etc. [There's a list here](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/shell/metachar.html). Otherwise it will start the program directly as the shell would do itself

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. So if Borodin had had a redirect in that multi-line `qx//` statement, it would have worked, correct?

Comment: @sferencik:  No. There are already wildcarded file names in there so it will be passed to the shell anyway. As I said in my update, the problem is that backslash followed by newline in a Perl double-quoted string is the same as just a newline: the backslash is removed so the shell never sees it. Backslash on its own is another shell metacharacter, so if you use single quotes or escape the backslash to stop it from being eaten then it would be passed to the shell and work fine. Getting metacharacters through multiple different languages with different rules is always awkward like this